# Renew command not working

Tags: macros

I have the following command written in my preamble

```
\renewcommand{\d}{\;\ensuremath\mathrm{d}}
```

but get the error

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \d invalid in math mode on input line 11.
```

This only happens on a couple of my documents, and I can't figure out why. This also happens when I redefine `\a`, `\b`, `\c` to other things (like vectors).

Comment: Without a MWE it's difficult to give any answer. It's most likely that the commands are refined later by some package. At least `\c` was predefined by tex for another purpose and possibly redefined by packages like `fontspec`. It is generally a very bad idea to define a global single letter macro in latex (or any programming language for that matter)

Comment: @YanZhou It is to be hoped that no *package* is redefining these macros!

Comment: @YanZhou aha! it was another package. Turns out hyperref redefines them.

Comment: @user321210 No. `hyperref` is absolutely 100% not doing that. Please see my answer below. You are overwriting basic macros at your peril. `hyperref` is not overwriting anything. If you were lucky, it would overwrite your redefinitions. Unfortunately, that is not happening - at least, not reliably, anyway.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues, really. The first is that it is an extremely bad idea to redefine basic TeX and LaTeX macros unless you absolutely know what you are doing.

The second is that `\;` is not valid outside maths mode.

Perhaps you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\drm}{\ensuremath{\;\mathrm{d}}}
\drm
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

This is a response to the [OP's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316213/renew-command-not-working/316215?noredirect=1#comment771648_316213)

> @YanZhou aha! it was another package. Turns out hyperref redefines
>   them.

***NO! It is not. `hyperref` is not doing this at all. Describing it this way is just wrong. I cannot emphasise this strongly enough: `hyperref` is not redefining these macros.***

Redefining `\d` to be `\mathrm{d}` or making `\a` or `\c` into macros for vectors is not at all like what a package such as `hyperref` is doing.

What we see in `hyperref`'s `puenc.def`, for example, are lines such as

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\d}{PU}[1]{#1\83\043}% U+0323
```

and

```
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\d}{PU}{\@empty}{\textdotbelow}%
```

These are telling TeX what `\d` does when the `PU` encoding is being used. This is fine because this macro is *designed* to be encoding-dependent. This is what you are meant to do if you are writing a new encoding which should support `\d`.

`hyperref` is ***not*** redefining `\d`. This is (or should be!) a ***new*** definition because the `PU` encoding doesn't even exist until `hyperref` sets it up.

What `hyperref` is doing, rather, is defining a new output encoding. Output encodings have to define certain things and may define more. `hyperref` is not ***overwriting*** existing definitions because the definitions it gives for `\c` and `\d` are part of the definition of the new encoding and that encodings definitions are isolated from the definitions of the same macros for other encodings.

That is, what `hyperref` is doing is fine. What you are trying to do is a Very Bad Idea. It is a Very Bad Idea precisely because these kinds of macros play a fundamental role in the typesetting process and redefining them will come back to bite you sooner or later.

Comment: You mean "not valid *outside* math mode"?

Comment: +1, but I'd add that, in general, it is also strongly recommended to not create single character macros like `\d` or `\c`, etc. (Of course, this is implied in your first point, but making it more explicit for new users seems advisable.)  ... of course, I now see that @YanZhou already made this point above..!

Comment: @jon In general, I agree. In this case, not so much. The usual reason they are bad choices is because it is much more likely people will inadvertently overwrite existing macros with something like `\a`. But that's not the case here, the overwriting is deliberate. If you're going to overwrite a primitive or low-level macro, it is no worse because the macro has a single-lettered name. It is no better to say `\renewcommand\end{...}` than `\newcommand\e{...}`....

Comment: On the equivalence, sure. But the problem is that people tend to create 'shorthands' by doing `\def\d{...}`, which is (I think) exactly what the OP is doing with the (re)definitions of `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, `\d`. So: sometimes people even do `\def\b{\begin{<env.>}}`, etc. Thus, the deeper problem (from a motivation perspective) is the single-letter redefinitions for shorthands, even if, from a TeX perspective, the deeper problem is actually the redefinition of (La)TeX internals. Both are reasons not to redefine `\d` --- and this should be stressed to new users.

Comment: @jon The OP is ***not*** doing `\def\d{...}`. The OP told us exactly what the OP is doing and that is `\renewcommand\d{...}`.  The OP knows these are redefinitions: `... when I redefine \a, \b, \c to other things ...`. So whatever you think is exactly what the OP is doing, that is not what the OP said the OP is doing. The usual issue is the one you describe - people use `\def` and don't know. People don't use `\renewcommand` and not know. (OK. It is possible. But that's not what seems to be happening here and would be most unusual.)

Comment: @cfr I've seen someone use `\renewcommand` to define a brand new command, simply because they took a `\renewcommand` somebody else had done for them as a model for defining any and all new commands :P (P.S. just an anecdote, I agree with you that our OP knows what they're doing and that what they're doing is not what they should be doing. I would say, though, that it's the one letter commands that people are most likely to want to define over and the least likely to understand the potential problems with that.)

Comment: @Au101 I knew somebody would know somebody who ... That's why I thought I'd better qualify it ;). But, as you say, I don't think it applies here. I think the OP knows just enough physics to start the chain reaction but not quite enough to see why that might not be a great idea.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the role of \a and \d in general. What are they exactly doing in the typsetting process? Is my pdf corrupt now?

Comment: @user321210 These commands determine which characters from fonts get used for particular input. Roughly, TeX has to know that when you type `a` and a particular encoding is active, which character it should use from the font. (It is actually more complicated than this, but this will do for now.) In addition to mapping individual characters like `a`, TeX can map macros like `\d`. And in addition to mapping to a single character, it can map to a combination of characters. In the case of `puenc.def`, the output encoding defined isn't used in the usual way but is used by `hyperref`, I think ...

Comment: ... for dealing with various complications involved in hyperlinking things. For example, some characters need to be substituted if they appear in bookmarks and so on. I don't know the details of how `hyperref` works, so I'm not sure exactly how these are used. But you are also, of course, overwriting or trying to overwrite these macros in whatever other encodings you are using. I don't know what you mean by 'corrupt' but you should absolutely correct this and recompile the PDF, yes!!! I don't know exactly what damage this will do, but these macros cannot be safely changed.

Comment: @user321210 `\d{}`, for example, is used to create the dot under accent. At least, that's what it does in OT1 and T1, for example.  (See the `fontenc` documentation for details.) You might think that if you don't need this accent, you can overwrite it. However, it is really not at all safe to do this however certain you are. Apart from anything else, `\d{}` may be used differently in other encodings and your document will use many different encodings (yes, even if you're using a unicode engine, this is still true). Do you know what they all are or whether `\d` is important for you in any?

Comment: I am aware (of course) that the OP wrote `\renewcommand` (which I switched to `\def` initially to get under the character limit). But I am not convinced that this necessarily indicates the degree of 'knowing' that you are ascribing to the OP. It could be as you say, but the subsequent comment suggests a less strong form of 'knowing'. & knowing *that* you are redefining (and not merely defining) something in order to create a shorthand macro does not impact whether the motivation to create single-character shorthands is good or bad practice. It's just, IMO, bad practice. Also likely dangerous.

Comment: @jon Have you seen the follow-up question? I thought it was quite funny that while we're debating this, the OP said they'd been told single letter commands are bad, but then [David goes and says that's not the important bit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316393/) ;).

Comment: @jon Partly my resistance is motivated by the fact that I've answered 2 questions in the past week in which the answer to the question was not to redefine `\value`. I think you're right about single letter macros being bad generally. But it really matters that people get why and don't just get the single-letters-bad bit.

Comment: @jon there is absolutely nothing wrong with using single letter names for personal shorthands. _lots_ of people use `\R` for `\mathbb{R}` etc. The only issue is that you should not redefine the internals of the system that you are using. redefining `\c` is bad for the same reason that redefining `\box` is bad, the fact that `c` is one letter is not really relevant.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I disagree when (1) you are using `\def` or `\renewcommand`(!) in a real `.tex` file (and not just for a quick test), and (2) if you don't know when and why it might be a bad idea. When either or both of those conditions hold, the motivation to create single-letter macros is, *generally*, a bad idea. And I think both conditions hold in the OP. I certainly don't recommend redefining `\box` (or `\value`, or ...) either. I'd also add that single-character macros names tend, generally, to lead to (unintentional) obfuscating of code, which makes it undesirable in the long run.

Comment: @jon But the problem is using `\def` or `\renewcommand` rather than `\newcommand`. If somebody will use `\newcommand` then they can use available single letters for macros without needing to know that much because if they get an error, they can just reject that choice. Knowing this is a much more general method than avoiding single letters, because the same method will protect other macros such as `\value` and `\box`. Otherwise, the rules are just arbitrary-seeming.

Comment: @cfr -- Again, please bear in mind that I upvoted the answer and simply suggested what I thought was a relatively minor addition to it. I get that you disagree and you have no problems with the motivation people have to create single-character macros; but I'm not, and was not, advocating that the claim 'it is an extremely bad idea to redefine basic TeX and LaTeX macros unless you absolutely know what you are doing' is wrong or that you should rewrite your answer. That is the reason for the upvote, after all. (Though of course all rules are arbitrary at any suitably deep level.)

Comment: But (and I wish now I didn't delete the earlier comment) perhaps we can agree to disagree at this point.