# sum of two variables

Tags: variable

how can I make the sum of 2 variables in cm?
Example:
\y+ \n 
\x + \m

Thank in advance

Minimal coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\x}{0.5cm}
\newcommand*{\y}{2.0cm}
\newcommand*{\m}{1.5cm}
\newcommand*{\n}{2.5cm}

\begin{document}
\title{Texblock color}

\textblockcolour{cyan}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(2cm,10cm)
  123 

\end{textblock*}
\textblockcolour{red}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(\x,\y+\n)
  456 
\end{textblock*}

\textblockcolour{yellow}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(\x+\m,16cm)
  789
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Either replace `\y+\n` with `\dimexpr\y+\n` or stay with `\y+\n` and use the `calc` package. Either way, I'd be careful with single letter commands, see also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316391/134144

Comment: You might want to use `\newlength` rather than `\newcommand`.

Comment: @cfr please give more details. Thanks

Comment: You're defining lengths, so `\newlength` is likely a better choice than `\newcommand`.

Comment: @cfr it don't work. Please help, my code in https://www.codepile.net/pile/YnDKGgqv. thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include new information.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not defining one-letter command, but to use a more semantic approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{mm}
 {
  \tl_clear_new:c { l_forti_var_#1_tl }
  \tl_set:cn { l_forti_var_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_forti_var_#1_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definevar{x}{0.5cm}
\definevar{y}{2.0cm}
\definevar{m}{1.5cm}
\definevar{n}{2.5cm}

\begin{document}
\title{Texblock color}

\textblockcolour{cyan}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(2cm,10cm)
  123 
\end{textblock*}

\textblockcolour{red}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(\usevar{x},\dimeval{\usevar{y}+\usevar{n}})
  456 
\end{textblock*}

\textblockcolour{yellow}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(\dimeval{\usevar{x}+\usevar{m}},16cm)
  789
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can still go the `\newcommand` way, with the same syntax with `\dimeval` to perform the operation, so like

```
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(\x,\dimeval{\y+\n})
```

if you prefer the style I don't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calculator` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\x}{0.5}
\newcommand{\y}{2}
\newcommand{\m}{1.5}
\newcommand{\n}{2.5}
\begin{document}
\ADD{\x}{\y}{\one}
\(\x\text{cm} + \y\text{cm} = \one\text{cm}\)

\ADD{\m}{\n}{\two}
And \(\m\text{cm} + \n\text{cm} = \two\text{cm}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Equation]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It's not only about making the computation but mostly about making it work in the argument of a `{textblock*}` environment.