# Problem with new command

Tags: macros

Since I'm taking a class in linear algebra, I often need to write M(mxn, K) and I find it annoying.

I tried to define a command: `\newcommand{\M}[3]{M(#1 \times #2, #3)}` but this gives a strange output:

[image]

Hoe can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: The definition looks ok so there is something else going on. That's why we always ask for a MWE...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you define

```
\newcommand{\M}[3]{M(#1 \times #2, #3)}
```

then the input syntax should be

```
\M{2}{2}{\mathbb{R}}
```

and ***not***

```
\M{2,2,\mathbb{R}}
```

which indeed reproduces the strange output and, possibly, some error messages.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}} % the reals

\newcommand{\M}[3]{M(#1\times #2,#3)}

\begin{document}

Good syntax \verb|\M{2}{2}{\RR}| yields $A\in\M{2}{2}{\RR}$

Bad syntax \verb|\M{2,2,\RR}| yields $A\in\M{2,2,\RR}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you get the, admittedly easier, syntax to work? Yes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{xparse}% not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}} % the reals

\NewDocumentCommand{\M}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\MLONG#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MLONG}{mmm}{M(#1\times #2,#3)}

\begin{document}

Good new syntax \verb|\M{2,2,\RR}| yields $A\in\M{2,2,\RR}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where's the secret? The preprocessor `\SplitArgument{2}{,}` tells LaTeX to read the argument, which should contain two commas, and pass `#1` as

```
{<a>}{<b>}{<c>}
```

when the argument is `<a>,<b>,<c>`. So we can feed the transformed argument to `\MLONG` that reads three standard arguments.

Comment: To be _extremely_ nit-picky `amsmath` isn't really necessary, is it?

Comment: `xparse` to the rescue! I really need to look into this more.

Comment: @Alenanno I added a bit of explanation

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I had already `+1`'ed anyways :D Just a question: even if the package doesn't need to be specified explicitly anymore, is the documentation still valid for knowing about the various options, commands, etc?

Comment: @Alenanno Some argument types, notably `g`, are not allowed in the kernel version. For them it's necessary to explicitly load the package.

Comment: @egreg Is this specified in the documentation too?

Comment: @Alenanno Still a bit vaguely: section 1.8.

Comment: It might be good to add a note on not creating single letter commands. +1

Comment: @RaoulKessels Possibly. However `\M` seems safe enough.

Comment: @RaoulKessels what may the problem be with single letter commands?

Comment: @egreg thank you very much for the solution

Comment: @user66094 Single letter commands are used internally to produce accented characters. If you redefine one, you will get wrong output. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316391/single-letter-macros. In general it is better to use longer macro names and it is usually recommended to use some prefix so that your own macros will not interfere with macros form other packages.

Comment: @RaoulKessels Right, but I used `\NewDocumentCommand{\M}`, no redefinition involved.

Answer (score 3):

As Campa said, you should always provide a `MWE`

For the moment, have a look at

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}
\newcommand{\M}[3]{\ensuremath{M(#1 \times #2, #3)}}
\begin{document}
\M{1}{2}{\mathbb{R}}
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

as expected.

Comment: Is there any real reason for `\ensuremath`?

Comment: @egreg Not really. But the OP did not give any context. So I guessed.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers identified, the problem was that you need to write `\M{2}{2}{R}` to use your macro in the document.

It's understandable that you'd like to avoid writing it that way, since curly braces are difficult to type. egreg showed a way to reduce (but not eliminate) curly braces with modern LaTeX.

If you want to use syntax similar to the way you wrote it in the text of your question, another approach is the old TeX-style definition

```
\def\M(#1x#2,#3){M(#1 \times #2, \mathbb{#3})}
```

Then you can write `\M(2x2,R)` in your document.